# .net NotSupportedException while creating file with date

Tags: .net, file, datetime, c++-cli, notsupportedexception

I want to create a file with date.

```
DateTime time_now = DateTime::UtcNow;
String^  time_str = time_now.UtcNow.ToString();
String^  strPath = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\VS\\MyProject\\" + fileName + time_str + ".prc";

FileStream^  fs = File::Create(strPath); // in this line I get notSupportedException
```

I debug the code and the file name is : myfile05.01.2012 12:37:1222.prc

I think the probles is ":"
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would replace the "." and ":" with "_" ;

`strPath.Replace(".","_").Replace(":","_");`

Comment: Problem is only with `:`, `.` is a valid character for a file name. The latter need not be replaced.

Comment: @DevendraD.Chavan true, I'm also suggesting losing the "." too as the file name has a suffix and convention is that "." delimits the suffix.

Comment: That's a quick solution to a very specific problem, not reusable, not safe against format changes. You can check and replace every invalid char with the solution i offered below.

Comment: @Baboon, agreed, yours is a much better solution, which is why I upvoted it.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell if it's JUST this one never-ever-changing occurence in his entire solution, and it's called thousands of times, yours is a better (more performant) solution. Which is why i'm upvoting it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Replace every invalid character with an underscore:

```
private string GetValidPath(string _Path)
        {
            String goodPath = _Path;
            foreach (char letter in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
            {
                goodPath = goodPath.Replace(letter, '_');
            }
            return goodPath;
        }
```

If you're programming in C++/CLI, you can hopefully port this C# code.